# While file data with regex

Tags: c, regex, while-loop

I have problem on while file data on get only regular expession. I would get only the sorted data table.

**My file:**

```
Foods list test.
Check all foods:
1   123456   Food Name 1
2   123457   Food Name 2
3   123458   Food Name 3
4   123459   Food Name 4
5   123460   Food Name 5
blablabla blablabla
...
file foods done
```

> ID\tCOD\t(SPACE)NAME

**My code:**

```
int id, cod;
char name[64];
FILE *file;
file = fopen("foods.txt", "r")
while(fscanf(file, "(\d+)\t(\d+)\t (.*)", &id, &cod, name) != EOF)
    printf("ID: %d - Code: %d - Name: %s\n", id, cod, nome);
```

Is not working as it should, why? You are entering an endless loop.

Answer (score 3):

The `scanf` function does not accept regular expressions.  It has its own syntax similar to `printf`.

Try this instead:

```
while(fscanf(file, "%d %d %s", &id, &cod, name) == 3)
```

Comment: How to use regular expressions?

Comment: It should be `&cod`, not `%cod`

Comment: @LouFranco I have line, example `5   123460   Food5 Good`, how to get 3 elements? id, cod, food name

Comment: You can't really do that with fscanf because it breaks on spaces. The easiest thing to do is to write your own parse function that does that and pass in the line.

Comment: @LouFranco  Thanks.  Fixed.